# Websphere Portlet migration, missing parameter in DispatchAction

Tags: java, migration, struts, portlet, websphere-portal

I'm migrating an old portlet application from WPS5 to WPS6. The application is using IBM legacy container. According to the migration guide, I only renew some portal library and some tag reference. The application is still using IBM legacy container and the modified Struts Portlet.

When I create a link like by:

```
<html:link page="/page1.do?method=display">Go to Page 1</html:link>
```

The link render such url:

```
/wps/.../...[hash-like chars]_spf_strutsAction=!2fpage1.do!3fmethod%3ddisplay#[hash-like chars]
```

I'm using `DispatchAction`, which would look up parameter '**method**' for dispatch. However, click on the above link cannot pass the '**method**' parameter to dispatchAction. Further investigation on the request parameter found out this key-value pair:

```
name: spf_strutsAction
value: !2fpage1.do!3fmethod=display
```

So it's quite obviously that `request.getParameter('method')` returns null because the parameter is buried under `request.getParameter('spf_strutsAction')` and thus the action cannot be dispatched.

Of course I can force the dispatch action by reading the buried parameter. But the problem is that there are many other parameter other than '**method**'.

I think that the portal server should provides its implementation of PortletRequest. Is that the PortletRequest.getParameter() is somehow incorrect? Or is it the Portlet Struts Problem? How can I put those parameters back inside the request object?

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

1. You could use the portlet tags to generate the links.
2. Check out the "newer" struts jars that come with IBM Portal 6.0
3. Consider using a better portlet web framework, such as Spring Portlet MVC, which is jsr168 compliant. IBM will not be supporting it's old portlet model in the future.